# Some languages and uses for monads

Tags: scala, functional-programming, clojure, lisp, monads

According to you, which language do you think would be the best for implementing monads (Python/Ruby/LISP)?,also can anyone tell me some possible uses of monads (please give examples),like exceptions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I changed the title because the previous one was misleading casual passers by to think this question was argumentative. To keep the question from being closed I edited the title.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[All About Monads](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads) - legendary tutorial that lists all the standard monads and gives a lot of real-world examples. 
Popular monads that you can meet even in the mainstream languages are `Maybe`, `List` and `Continuation`. 
Some people also think that jQuery itself is a monad (as it follows the [monadic axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Axioms)).
As for the language choice, Haskell and its derivatives are using monads as a fundamental concept, however, as an option, constructing monads is possible in a lot of modern languages. In order to familiarize with the monad concept I'd better choose the language I'm the most comfortable with.

Comment: "All about monads" seems to have disappeared :( .. the closest I can find is here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads (this is first of 6 pages). If you see the original article again, please let me know.

Comment: jQuery is *almost* a monad. Its `map` is half `map` and half `concatMap` in a sort of messy confusing way. If you cleaned its semantics up properly, things would be much more straightforward.

Comment: "All About Monads" do exist. Visit http://horna.org.ua/books/All_About_Monads.pdf.

Answer (score 7):

In order of preference:

1. Haskell
2. F#
3. Scala
4. C#

Monads in order of decreasing simplicity:

1. Maybe (Exception)
2. Reader
3. Writer
4. State
5. Parser
6. Async

Comment: No OCaml or is that listed with F#?

Comment: Ocaml have no builtin syntactic sugar for monad unfortunately

Comment: Scala > F#. Why? Simple. In Scala you can write functions operating on any monad, which you can't in F#, because that requires higher-kinded types.

Comment: Because i know f# better :) But in f# i can write some functions operating on any monad with compile-time type resolution.

Comment: Good list, but I would also put Scala above F#.  I'd also add List and Set between Maybe and Reader, and Continuation between Parser and Async.

Comment: Async - is continuation monad. List usualy already implemented in all languages supporting monads. I just frogot him.

Comment: Scala belongs higher than F# regarding "language ... best for implementing monads ". Scala has higher-order polymorphism, allowing the expression of the monad abstraction. F# does not, disallowing it.

Comment: You forgot the simplest monad of all: Identity!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tutorial that use clojure. Monads are implemented in a library.

- http://onclojure.com/2009/03/05/a-monad-tutorial-for-clojure-programmers-part-1/
- http://onclojure.com/2009/03/06/a-monad-tutorial-for-clojure-programmers-part-2/
- http://onclojure.com/2009/03/23/a-monad-tutorial-for-clojure-programmers-part-3/

Comment: although monads are not idiomatic in clojure (in most cases there is a alt way to get the same objective with other langs features), and its official implmentation has a lot of macro hackery, it's possible to use them. I would add another tutorials: http://intensivesystems.net/tutorials/monads_101.html , http://erl.nfshost.com/2010/09/05/bind-unit-and-all-that-2 and http://onclojure.com/2009/06/24/protecting-mutable-state-in-the-state-monad/

Answer (score 1):

For examples, see Philip Wadler, "Monads for functional programming".